# Webview Problem in android emulator

Tags: android

I am having difficulty in opening a webview within my application.

I can open it within other applications but not the one I want.

Also I can only open up webpages using

```
startActivity(new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

I am not sure why I cannot open webviews, I need this to work as I have a view within my application.

The way I am opening the webview is

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview);
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById( R.id.link4_view );          
wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

I do not receive any error in logcat, just says web page not available.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7347059/1531971

Answer (score 3):

Have you put internet permission into your AndroidManifest.xml file?

It should look like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" .... >
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work properly was by taking out the permission then loading the application. Then closing it and re-adding the permission and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Simple WebView Activity

Java Class Activity File - Code Snippet

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
WebView MyWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);        
MyWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MyWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

XML Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webkit" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="none" />
</ScrollView>
```

And Make Sure You Have Added Permission To Your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have put the XML layout file within my main xml file and this still shows the same web page not available.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes WebView is not working on emulator running on operating system due to internet sharing problem. You can try it by running on external android device.